# Wordpress comment spam leaving me locked out

Tags: wordpress

I run a Wordpress site for my company, and lately we've been getting comment spam to the point of triggering a lockout for 20+ hours at a time. I can't log in, nor can any of my coworkers. We whitelisted our IP address, but still keep getting locked out.

Is this a common occurrence? I can't imagine I'm the only person to run into this specific issue, but Google has as of yet been unhelpful...

I took it up with my managed hosting provider - WPEngine - who told me that I needed to whitelist our office IP (done, didn't help) and, if we get locked out, run a SQL query on our production database:

```
SELECT option_value AS row_count
FROM wp_options
WHERE option_name =  "limit_login_lockouts"
```

Which, y'know, doesn't actually do anything, just tells me that, if I'm reading this right, we've gotten something like 1.4 billion attempts to log in from an IP address that coincides with the Linode datacenter WPEngine has us sitting in.

Long-winded, sorry, but my question is twofold: what should I do to clear this up temporarily to let me log in, and what do you do/have you done to avoid this issue?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried using another IP (*another location*) rather than your offices? If you have cPanel access you might wanna check your access logs and look for any fishy IPs. Also check to see if your IP is on IP "Deny list".

Hope this helps